How can I add "None" to a View Filter's options?
My company has a Drupal 10 site that I have to interact with. I do not know Drupal very well.
Some of our users are associated with a regional headquarters, stored as a field in the database.  I have a view that includes a filter for Regional_HQ that allows me to select all users associated with a given site.
In the view configuration, the Filter Criteria is listed as User: Regional_HQ (exposed).  The filter is exposed to visitors, and the Options listing for it reads as
Select all
Atlanta
Baltimore
Cleveland
Denver
...

On the view page itself, this appears as a drop down menu
Regional HQ:

- Any -
Atlanta
Baltimore
Cleveland
Denver
...

I would like to be able to select all users that have no assigned Regional HQ.  I understand that I can expose the filter operator to the user and let the user select "Is one of" or "Is none of," but this increases the complexity of the view and the number of selections the user has to navigate.  A preferable approach is to add "None" to the drop down menu:
Regional HQ:

- Any -
- None -
Atlanta
Baltimore
Cleveland
Denver
...

This amounts to recognizing the SQL NULL value on equal footing with the non-null field values, so it seems reasonable to expect that Drupal 10 is capable of it.  However, I can't find a way to do it through the UI, and I can't find any information online that covers it.
Is it possible to add "None" to a View Filter drop-down selector?

This amounts to recognizing the SQL NULL value on equal footing with the non-null field values In this case it doesn't - if there's no value, there's no database record, so no NULL to compare against. What you want is a WHERE NOT EXISTS or similar, which you'd need to programatically manipulate the query to achieve

In this case, does "programatically manipulate the query" mean a custom module?

Unless you can find an existing module which happens to have the same feature, yes
